# integer part of the root withot using functions

Tags: python

The calculation of the integer part of the square root of a number can be done by trial and error, starting from 1, by executing the square until the result is less than or equal to the starting value of which is calculated by the root.

The following program returns the integer part of the root

```
def radice(x):
    z = 0
    t = 0
    while True:
        t = z*z
        if t > x:
            z -= 1
            return z
        z += 1

radice(17) // 4
```

Will be possible to write it without using functions and break? 
Here is my code witout function but I dont' know how to write the same algo with no `break`

```
z = 0
t = 0
while True:
    t = z*z
    if t > x:
        z -= 1
        break
    z += 1
print 'The integer part of the root is: ', z
```

Comment: @Volatility I tried to explain it better. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Do you see the algorithm inside this function? Why don't you just take it and use without the function itself?

Comment: @unkulunkulu I tried and I updated my question. The issue is about also the `break` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the integer part of the square root of a number can be done by trial and error, starting from 1, by executing the square until the result is less than or equal to the starting value of which is calculated by the root.
Said that you can write the code without using function and break statements; here is the code:

```
n = input("insert a number: ")
r = 1
while (r * r <= n):
        r = r + 1

print  "the result is:", r -1
```

Answer (score 3):

This should suffice:

```
>>> int(17**0.5)
4
```

`17**0.5` generates the square root of 17, and `int` basically removes the decimals, leaving you with the "integer part of the root".

Without using any functions, and if you want an integer result, complex code (like your own) is needed. However, if a float will do, then you could try this:

```
>>> (17**0.5)//1
4.0
```

This essentially does the same as the `int` call, but will return a float if either side is a float.

Comment: I would like  to use while loop and for.

Comment: the goal is to compute the integer part of the root for atttempts!

Comment: @Volatility, The point of the question is to compute this in integer arithmetic only. OP tries to explain this but fails (look at his comments in this answer). While your answer is practical, it doesn't take into account the homework nature of the question.

Comment: @unkulunkulu fair enough. Although this is a terrible homework question.

Answer (score 0):

Parens are for clarity, not required

```
>>> (17**.5)-(17**.5)%1
4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's think logically.
You cannot use `break`, so the only way to get out of the `while` loop is to break its condition.
If it's `True`, it cannot be broken, so we have to think about the proper condition to stop iterating. And this condition is already used in your algorithm: you exit when `t > x`, or `z * z > x`. So the condition to continue iteration should be the opposite, i.e. `z * z <= x`. And we have this simple solution.

```
x = 17
z = 0
while z * z <= x:
    z += 1

print 'The integer part of the root is: ', z - 1
```

As a general rule, try to shy away from those `while True:` loops. While they are sometimes useful, they're generally harder to read and understand, this is probably why your teacher limits the use of `break`. The function was prohibited probably because `return` is just another way of escaping the loop. But those are exceptional: the normal way to end a loop is to break its condition, so this is how it should be written.